# how to record a testscript using jmeter in any browser

Tags: jmeter

I want to do performance testing using Jmeter.I am new to jMeter tool,i am using 2.12 version of JMeter. I am trying to record a script in any of the browser. After clicking on start button in 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder',it shown a pop-up window withb this message: "RootCA Certificate:ApacheJmeterTemporaryRootCA created in Jmeter bin directory", then i have installed that certificate from Jmeter bin folder to firefox browser(V26.0).Even after completion of installation of certificate, i am trying to start recording by clicking on Start button, i am getting same pop up window.i have followed below link: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder 
please check the screen shot too..
can you please suggest me if any changes or suggestions are there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue, You can proceed with the recording. Certificate pop-up will always be prompted when you start the recording.

In order to proceed, you need to mention the proxy settings in Network settings of the browsers. Please make sure the PORT number mentioned in the Global Settings of "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" and in the Proxy settings in the browser are same.

[image: Jmeter Test Recorder]

[image: Browser]

Test Plan should be like below image:

[image: Test Plan]

After you start accessing your website/portal in the browser, you will see requests getting recorded under *Recording Controller*.

If you are facing any other issue while recording, please update your question with the same.

Hope this will help.

Comment: i have prepared testplan as u suggested.After i have started accessing my website in the firefox browser, i did not get any requests under Recording Controller.can you please suggest me

Comment: After changing the browser settings, and starting the "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" are your pages loading correctly in the browser?
if so, then try after closing & reopening the browser.

Comment: I have closed firefox browser and deleted the cookies also  and then started firefox and started recording.while recording comments  are like this only

Comment: [2014/12/29 19:04:33 INFO-jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca: 
2014/12/29 19:04:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for:intermediate_ca: 
2014/12/29 19:04:33 INFO-jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port:3128 
2014/12/29 19:04:33 INFO-jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon:Test Script Recorder up and running! 
2014/12/29 19:05:42 INFO-jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped]                                            But recording requests are not shown in scriptRecorder

Comment: remove Jmeter certificates from the firefox, Close and open the browser again. Also after doing this while launching your portal/website in browser if prompted, add certificates to the browser & make sure you have unchecked "permanently" checkbox.

Comment: Even now also i am unable to get recording requests in Recording controller, please help me